# Reduce time complexity of the word searching program

Tags: c, time-complexity

I'm trying to look up for the most frequent word in a text. In my program, The judging system(PC^2) will input some words ,divider, and some texts. The words and texts are separate by "-----"
(I need to search for the most frequent word in my program).

### Input

```
apple
an
banana
-----
i like an apple.
i also like apple-pie.
i like banana
i like banana+ice.
```

### Output

```
apple 2
banana 2
```

- The character which is not digit, alphabet, and '_' should be treated as space
- The longest length of each line is 1024
- The order of output should be in `strcmp` order

However, Although the program runs great when being tested by me. I got Time Limit Exceeded(TLE) from PC^2. Therefore, I want to ask how can I improve the time complexity in my program? I got even TLE before displaying the most frequent word and its frequency.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char tmp[2048];
char **dicWord;
int *dicWcount;
int dic_assume_num = 1000, dic_actual_num = 0;

int main()
{
    char divider[6] = "-----";
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    size_t nbytes = 2047;
    char *my_string;

    // first, get the input of words
    dicWord = malloc( dic_assume_num * sizeof( *dicWord ));
    my_string = malloc((nbytes + 1) * sizeof(*my_string));

    while ((bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin)) != -1) {
        my_string[strcspn(my_string, "\n")] = '\0';

        if (strncmp(my_string, divider, 5) == 0) {
            dicWcount = calloc(dic_actual_num+1,  sizeof(*dicWcount));
            break;
        }

        else {
            dicWord[dic_actual_num++] = strdup(my_string);
            if (dic_actual_num >= dic_assume_num) {
                dic_assume_num *= 2;
                dicWord = realloc( dicWord, dic_assume_num * sizeof( *dicWord ));
            }
        }
    }

    // second, get the input of text
    int cnt;
    for (;;) {
        scanf("%*[^a-zA-Z0-9_]");
        cnt = scanf("%2047[a-zA-Z0-9_]", tmp);

        if (cnt != 1) {
            break;
        }


        for ( size_t i = 0; i < dic_actual_num; ++i) {

            if (strcmp(dicWord[i], tmp) == 0) {
                dicWcount[i]++;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < dic_actual_num; ++i)
        free(dicWord[i]);

    free(dicWord);
    free(dicWcount);
    free(my_string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*may not be infinite loop. Instead, my program may run more than expected time.*" -- you should make sure about this, e.g. by debugging. If your program has *wrong* behavior, the question probably belongs here, but make sure to create a [mcve] (including input, expected and actual output). If, on the other hand, the program **does** work correctly, you might want to have a look at codereview.stackexchange.

Comment: You say that you have asked this question already. The question you link to does not seem very similar. It has however been answered by referring you to a duplicate question. Please elaborate what the difference between the three questions is and what problem in this question here has not been answered by the other two. If this is actually a new question (as it seems), then I recommend to remove the confusing reference to unrelated questions, or to refer more precisely to a part of the other question you want to contrast this one against.

Comment: @Felix the program works great when being tested by me. But it failed on a judging system(PC^2).

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for suggetion. I've modified it.

Comment: One major item is that the 'my_string` copies are not being passed to `free()` at the end of the program.  The result is a major memory leak.

Comment: Strongly suggest placing both a pointer to char and a counter into a struct definition  Use an array of that struct as the base of the data array.  Then use `strdup()` to duplicate the resulting string from `getline()` into the array.  That will eliminate a lot of the (probably 50%) of the calls to `malloc()`  (and `malloc()` takes some time. to execute.

Comment: Please post a link to the actual online question that this code is trying to solve.  Then we can perform a much better analysis and give you much better suggestions on what you should modify.

Comment: the posted code is calling `scanf()` twice in a row.  This is totally unneeded.  A bit of work with the format string would fix this problem.  However, note that `scanf()` is very CPU intensive, so is a poor way to input the individual words.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  It is missing the needed `#include` statements.  Do you expect us to guess as to which header files your code actually includes?

Comment: user3629246 `#include` statements are added

Comment: this statement: `char *my_string;`  should be: `char *my_string = NULL;`  and this statement: `my_string = malloc((nbytes + 1) * sizeof(*my_string));` removed.  Also, when calling `getline()` in a loop, always reset the length count and the pointer to char before each call to `getline()`   Note: `getline()` is a rather expensive call, in terms of CPU cycles. so you might want to rethink your plan to use it.

Comment: the (with headers) code 1) contains several comparisons between `signed` and `unsigned` numbers.   2) the code contains several 'implicit' conversions between various numeric types.   Both of these problem types can lead to errors in the numeric values.

Comment: the posted code does not contain any 'sorting' algorithm.  The posted code does not contain any display of the resulting values nor selected words

Answer (score 0):

**The idea is simple:**

- Iterate through the text/ file: **O(n)**
- Add the current word to a Tree/ Hashtable/ Map of words already seen
  or increase the counter for this word: **n*log(n)**
- After iterating through the file: get the word with the highest counter: **O(1)**

What most influences the time needed is the data structure you are using to store the words. A balanced tree (word with highest counter as root) should be fine.

I don't think its possible to reduce the time needed even more.

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. is reasonably fast
3. performs the desired operations, except sorting the output

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct myData
{
    char   word[1026];
    size_t count;
};


struct myData dicWord[ 1000 ];  // may need to increase the 1000


int main( void )
{
    size_t dic_actual_num = 0;

    // first, get the input of words
    while ( fgets(dicWord[ dic_actual_num ].word, 1026, stdin) )
    {
        dicWord[ dic_actual_num ].word[ strcspn( dicWord[ dic_actual_num ].word, "\n") ] = '\0';

        if (strncmp( dicWord[ dic_actual_num ].word, "-----", 5 ) == 0)
        {
             break;
        }

        dic_actual_num++;
    }

    // second, get the input of text and check for highest count
    char tmp[1026];  // +2 for newline and NUL byte
    size_t maxCount = 0;

    while( 1 == scanf( "%*[^a-zA-Z0-9_] %1024[a-zA-Z0-9_]", tmp ) )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < dic_actual_num; ++i)
        {
            if (strcmp(dicWord[i].word, tmp) == 0)
            {
                dicWord[i].count++;
                if( dicWord[i].count > maxCount )
                {
                    maxCount = dicWord[i].count;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // << need to add logic for `strcmp()` sorting


    // display answer
    for( size_t i = 0; i<dic_actual_num; i++ )
    {
        if( maxCount == dicWord[i].count )
        {
            printf( "%s %lu\n", dicWord[i].word, maxCount );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: added function to replace the calls to 'scanf()'

Caveat: this proposed function has not been tested

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// prototype:
char *getWord( void );


char *getWord()
{
    static char newWord[1026];

    //memset( newWord, '\0', sizeof( newWord ) );

    size_t charCount = 0;
    int  ch;

    // skip leading junk
    while( (ch = getchar_unlocked) != EOF 
         || '\n' == ch 
         || ispunct( ch ) 
         || isspace( ch ) );

    // append desired characters
    while( charCount < 1024
        && (ch = getchar_unlocked) != EOF 
        && ( '_' == ch || isdigit( ch ) || isalpha( ch ) ) )
    {
        newWord[ charCount ] = ch;
        charCount++;
    }

    // terminate the string
    newWord[ charCount ] = '\0';

    return newWord;
}
```

Comment: In addition to `scanf`, is there an other or better way to flush the invalid characters?

Comment: a better way, rather than use `scanf()` is to write a small function to input each word,  Such a function would use `getchar_unlocked()` it would accumulate each word, then return a pointer to that word.   Such a function would be MUCH faster than calling `scanf()`

Comment: the first `(ch = getchar_unlocked) != EOF` in while loop will be true constantly until the end of input?

Comment: @LINPOHSIEN,  Well, I did say the function was not tested.